# How to get shared screen video on iOS using SfB (Skype for business) SDK

Tags: android, ios, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm developing an application (iOS/Android) with SfB SDK.
Couldn't find a way to receive shared screen streaming from desktop application.
Basically I need to show desktop Skype For Business application's shared screen on my device , NOT my device's shared screen.
Any help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that feature is not supported in the SDK atm.  I can't find evidence of this though.

Answer (score -1):

Sharing desktop on iOS is not supported yet, checked in version 0.8 iOS SDK

**Update 1:**
Version 1.3: still no desktop sharing for iOS